# Shell scripts stops writing in log file

Tags: shell, logging

I am working on a provisioner shell script which after certain tasks writes in a log file. The problem is that after the third write operation it stops and doesn't log anything else, however the script runs successfully with the rest of the operations.

I am using this most simple command:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit

# Set variables
APACHE_USER="www-data"
STORES_PATH="/var/www/x/stores"
LOG_FILE="deploy_store.log"

NEW_DB_PWD="$(openssl rand -base64 12)"

arg1="${1:-}"
echo "'$arg1' provision started on $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" >> "${LOG_FILE}"
git clone git@bitbucket.org:x/y.git ${STORES_PATH}"/$arg1"
echo "Done cloning the repository." >> "${LOG_FILE}"

# Link the store vendor folder
ln -s /srv/x/vendor_5.7 ${STORES_PATH}"/$arg1/vendor"
echo "Done linking the vendor folder." >> "${LOG_FILE}"

# Run the setup composer commands
cd ${STORES_PATH}"/$arg1" && composer dump-autoload
cd ${STORES_PATH}"/$arg1" && php artisan package:discover --ansi
cd ${STORES_PATH}"/$arg1" && php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
cd ${STORES_PATH}"/$arg1" && php artisan key:generate
echo "Done composer setup." >> "${LOG_FILE}" # THIS IS NOT LOGGED.
```

Comment: Looks fine. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Side note, you could put `exec > deploy_store.log` at the top of your script to redirect all future standard output to the log file. You wouldn't need `>>` on every line.

Comment: Still it should be `exec >> deploy_store.log` instead of `exec > deploy_store.log`.

Comment: Someone could rename the directory the log file is in, then any subsequent writing to this path will simply fail (not silently, though).  And you could have weird characters (spaces and such) in your path.  You should always use double quotes around the use of a variable:  `echo "foo" >> "${LOG_FILE}"`.

Comment: Putting in exec on the top solved the issue indeed, however now everything is getting logged into the log file (composer, git output etc.), and I wanted to decide explicitly what to log.